# How Do I Debug A Notepad++ DLL Plugin?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to write a plugin for Notepad++ using Visual Studio Community 2013

The dll builds fine from the solution and if I copy it to the notepad++/plugins directory I can test out the functionality. However, I now want to debug it and I can't launch the debugger. I tried following a [paint.net guide](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/4209-how-to-debug-your-plugin/) but I still get the error

```
Unable to start program .....dll
```

On my project properties under Configuration Properties - Debugging I have the following set:

```
Command = C:\tools\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
Working Directory = C:\tools\Notepad++
```

Configuration Properties - Build Events - Post-Build Event I have:

```
Command Line = copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\tools\Notepad++\plugins"
```

NB: The path is outside Program Files to avoid UAC issues when copying.

What other options could be causing this issue?

Comment: You tried following a Paint.NET guide in order to debug a DLL for Notepad++??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you skimmed the guide, you'd see that it's general instructions for launching a host application in order to debug a plugin DLL.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Badly named, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to having multiple Configurations in the solution.

Deleting old and unused ones from the sln and vcxproj files cleaned things up. Then making sure that the configuration options were set to All Configurations fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have a debug build of your DLL built with symbols enabled, and use the **Debug -> Attach to Process** menu command to attach to the notepad++ process once it's running.

Comment: I'm only debugging the plugin and not Notepad++ itself.

Comment: @opticyclic You can't debug a DLL as such, you need to debug the process the DLL is loaded into.